# Filter pandas DataFrame by membership in set-of-tags

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Let's say that I have a DataFrame containing a list or set of tags and I want to filter the DataFrame based on whether a certain tag is part of this row, what is the most idiomatic way to achieve this with pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'amount': [15, 20, 40],
    'tags': [["Food", "Eating Out"], ["Food", "Groceries"], ["Clothes"]],
    'description': ["Garfunkel's", "Tesco", "Hollister"]
})
```

I have this piece of code that works, but is rather clunky to write:

```
criterion = lambda row: 'Food' in row['tags']
df[df.apply(criterion, axis=1)]
```

The result should be:

[image: result]

Comment: Having multiple values in a single cell isn't particularly idiomatic in `pandas`- I do it myself sometimes but it makes it pretty difficult to use typical `pandas` idioms. Your current solution looks pretty decent considering, I'm not sure how much better you're going to get.

Comment: Was this one of the Kaggle shopping competitions?

Comment: In fact you can convert your strings to `Categoricals`, no need to string-match every time (assuming the complete set of tags is known).

Comment: Oh that is interesting, smci. Yes, I could in fact generate the complete set of tags.

Comment: When you say "set of tags", do you mean set or list? Testing membership in a list is O(N), set is O(1). Categoricals are more compact in memory than set-of-string, and testing them is just a straight integer comparison.

Comment: @smci I didn't specify that because I can change that pretty easily. Sets are obviously a better fit for this, but if there's something that only works for lists it would be fine because N is very low.

Comment: Separate Categorical/boolean columns are better than a column containing set or list, that will really mess up vectorization. Try it yourself and prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply a `lambda` to only the relevant column, instead of the whole row:

```
df[df['tags'].map(lambda tags: 'Food' in tags)]
```

Comment: I used to write code like this, it's very slow to search a list every single row every single time you want to do logical-indexing. Set/list-of-string is also much worse on memory. Avoid.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the least invasive change to make it work, even though @smci is definitely right that I should slice my data in a different way to query it more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

For efficiency, searching list-of-string-tags every time you want to do logical indexing will be bad. So:

**Expand `df['tags']` into multiple columns.** Either:

- if there are at most T tags, add T boolean columns `df['tFood'] = [ 'Food' in tt for tt in df['tags'] ]`
- if each item can have at most N tags and N is small, then add string columns tag1,tag2...tagN. In fact you can convert your string to Categoricals, no need to string-match every time.

Now, you can do logical indexing quickly:

```
df.loc[df['tFood']==True,]
# amount  description                tags tFood
# 0      15  Garfunkel's  [Food, Eating Out]  True
# 1      20        Tesco   [Food, Groceries]  True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Its not a perfect solution but it works.

```
print df[df['tags'].astype(str).str.contains('Food')]
```

You can even use regular expressions in contains() to match multiple patterns.